# Passing objects from a controller to a twig view

Tags: php, twig

I'm using symfony 4.4. I'm trying to pass an array of objects to a twig view, but I'm not able to.I call the controller with a render.

twig-> `{% set versiones = render(path('app_getVersions', {'appId':app.getId()})) %}`

```
    /**
     * @Route("/bugs/errores/versions/{appId}", name="app_getVersions", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function getVersions($appId)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $app = $em->getRepository(Aplicaciones::class)->findOneBy(['id' => $appId]);
        $versiones = $em->getRepository(Aplicaciones::class)->app_nDownload($app->getId())['versiones'];

        $versionesArray = array_map(function ($version) {
            return [
                'id' => $version->getId(),
                'fecha' => $version->getFecha()->format('Y-m-d'),
                'changelog' => $version->getChangelog(),
                'dataDirectoryDownload' => $version->getDataDirectoryDownload(),
                'nversion' => $version->getNversion(),
                'ndescargas' => $version->getNdescargas(),
            ];
        }, $versiones);

        return $this->json($versionesArray);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/bugs/errores/reports/{versionId}", name="app_getReports", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function getReports($versionId): Response
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $reports = $em->getRepository(VersionBugs::class)->findBy(['versionesapp' => $versionId]);
        $reportsArray = array_map(function ($versionBugs) {
            return [
                'id' => $versionBugs->getId(),
                'reporte' => $versionBugs->getReporte(),
                'versionesapp' => $versionBugs->getVersionesapp(),
                'user_reporter' => $versionBugs->getUserReporter()
            ];
        }, $reports);

        return $this->json($reportsArray);

    }
```

The problem is that the object arrives at the twig view as follows:

`[{"id":0,"fecha":"2023-04-01","changelog":"Ahora la arena permite desbloquear nuevos ","dataDirectoryDownload":"https:\/\/storage.evozi.com\/apk\/dl\/17\/04\/14\/com.supercell.clashroyale_0.apk","nversion":"10.2","ndescargas":2},{"id":10,"fecha":"2021-12-05","changelog":"A\u00f1adido soporte para pantallas plegables","dataDirectoryDownload":"https:\/\/storage.evozi.com\/apk\/dl\/17\/04\/14\/com.supercell.clashroyale_0.apk","nversion":"4.5.1","ndescargas":0},{"id":16,"fecha":"2023-05-14","changelog":"Nuevo personage gigante","dataDirectoryDownload":"https:\/\/storage.evozi.com\/apk\/dl\/17\/04\/14\/com.supercell.clashroyale_0.apk","nversion":"11","ndescargas":23}]`

And I can't get the for of the twig to go through it, why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `return $this->json($reportsArray)`?